# What is this, and how was it made?

Tags: support, profile-page

I've seen quite a few users have this on their profile description.

[image]

It looks an image format of the user with his rep and badges. So, what is it exactly? How can I add this to my profile?

Comment: See https://stackexchange.com/users/10446039/pritt-balagopal?tab=flair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a flair.

You can get your per site flair or network flair on the edit profile -> flair section.

You can get your network flair from this link

https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flair

You have to copy paste the HTML code provided there

[image]

In above sectio, scrolling a bit down will show the network flair.

The code will looks like

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/<userid>">
<img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/<userid.png>" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for i-- on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for i-- on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites">
</a>
```